# Join Concatenation of Formatted XSLT node values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this block of XML code

```
         <itemContentList>
            <itemContent condition="sometype">
               <typeList1>
                  <type1 otherName="companion">other</type1>
               </typeList1>
               <typeList2 condition="anothertype" xlink:href="value1"/>
            </itemContent>
            <itemContent condition="sometype">
               <typeList1>
                  <type1 otherName="companion2">other</type1>
               </typeList1>
               <typeList2 condition="anothertype" xlink:href="value2"/>
            </itemContent>
            <itemContent condition="sometype">
               <typeList1>
                  <type1 otherName="companion3">other</type1>
               </typeList1>
               <typeList2 condition="anothertype" xlink:href="value3"/>
            </itemContent>          
         </itemContentList>
```

My desired output is a semi-colon separated values of a formatted string from the nodes.

```
(companion,value1);(companion2,value2);(companion3,value3)
```

I used this particular XSL transformation:

```
<xsl:variable name="desiredOutput">
      <xsl:for-each select="itemContentList">
        <xsl:variable name="param1"
            select="itemContent[@condition='sometype']/typeList1/type1/@otherName"/>
        <xsl:variable name="param2" 
            select="itemContent[@condition='sometype']/typeList2[@condition='anothertype']/@xlink:href"/>                               
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join((concat('(', string-join(($param1, $param2)[.!=''],','),')')),';')"/>         
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

But the output turns out differently:

```
(companion,companion2,companion3,value1,value2,value3)
```

I also extracted the string-join as a function but it renders the same. Any help with this?

EDIT 1:

Thank you for the help! Although my goal is to save the value of the concatenated string in a variable.

For both solutions, I tried using the template and assign a name to it. Both answers provide the string that I was trying to generate.

```
<xsl:template **name="concatvalue"** match="/itemContentList">
    <xsl:value-of select="for $i in itemContent return concat('(', $i/typeList1/type1/@otherName, ',', $i/typeList2/@xlink:href, ')')" separator=";"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then I created a variable that performs:

```
  <xsl:variable name="concatvariable">
    <xsl:call-template name="concatvalue" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

However, "concatvariable" is empty.

Comment: What is your XSLT version?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky XSLT 2.0

Comment: Patrick, I updated the answer and added use of a variable. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar solution, just without the FLWOR.

I had to add a missing namespace.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<itemContentList xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <itemContent condition="sometype">
        <typeList1>
            <type1 otherName="companion">other</type1>
        </typeList1>
        <typeList2 condition="anothertype" xlink:href="value1"/>
    </itemContent>
    <itemContent condition="sometype">
        <typeList1>
            <type1 otherName="companion2">other</type1>
        </typeList1>
        <typeList2 condition="anothertype" xlink:href="value2"/>
    </itemContent>
    <itemContent condition="sometype">
        <typeList1>
            <type1 otherName="companion3">other</type1>
        </typeList1>
        <typeList2 condition="anothertype" xlink:href="value3"/>
    </itemContent>
</itemContentList>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/itemContentList">
        <xsl:value-of select="itemContent/concat('(', typeList1/type1/@otherName, ',', typeList2/@xlink:href, ')')" separator=";"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
(companion,value1);(companion2,value2);(companion3,value3)
```

**XSLT 2.0 with a variable**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="concatvariable">
    <xsl:value-of select="/itemContentList/itemContent/concat('(', typeList1/type1/@otherName, ',', typeList2/@xlink:href, ')')" separator=";"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$concatvariable"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yep, that's simpler.

Comment: Nope, that's not a good way to define the variable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, please update your answer and show how to do it better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794477/join-concatenation-of-formatted-xslt-node-values/64795044?noredirect=1#comment114569149_64794899

Comment: @Patrick, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: I was able to save the value in a variable by tweaking the above provided solution without the template:

```
    <xsl:variable name="concatValue">
      <xsl:for-each select="/itemContentList">
        <xsl:value-of select="/itemContent/concat('(', typeList1/type1/@otherName, ',', typeList2/@xlink:href, ')')" separator=";"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/itemContentList">
    <xsl:value-of select="for $i in itemContent return concat('(', $i/typeList1/type1/@otherName, ',', $i/typeList2/@xlink:href, ')')" separator=";"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4ub

Comment: This one worked, thank you! Though I wanted to store this value in a variable, I tried doing enclosing the xsl:value-of in a xsl:variable but it fails

Comment: Try `xsl:variable name="..." select="..."/>`  with the same *select* expression as the one above. Or the one below, which is simpler.